# Install Multiple Blackberry WebWorks SDK's With Signing

Tags: blackberry-webworks, blackberry-10, blackberry-playbook

I am trying to install the Blackberry 10 SDK as well as the PlayBook SDK for Blackberry and can't get the signing to work.  I set up the signing and registered the keys for the Blackberry 10 SDK no problem.  I then installed the Blackberry PlayBook SDK and then tried to register the keys for it also.  I tried to register the same keys as for the BB10 SDK and new keys just for the PB SDK and in both cases I get the error "Error: Already registered with RDK".  When I build the BB10 app it works okay and builds the app with signing.  When I try to build the PB app I get the message "Cannon sign the application - failed to find signing keys".

I have read through the documentation and I can't see anywhere on how to set up signing with multiple SDK's on one machine.  I am sure this can be done, but can't seem to figure out how it should be done to get the singing working.

SDK's:

- BB10-WebWorks-SDK_1.0.4.11
- WebWorks-Tablet-Win-v2.2

OS: Windows 8

Comment: Can you confirm the location of your author.p12, barsigner.csk and barsigner.db files? It should be something like this - %HOMEPATH%\AppData\Local\Research In Motion

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to register code signing keys more than once.

When you were emailed the *.csj files from BlackBerry, you installed them on your machine using these instructions:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup_bb10_apps_2008396_11.html

Doing so generates *.p12 and *.db and *.csk files in the following folder:
%HOMEPATH%\Local Settings\Application Data\Research In Motion

Both the BB10 and PlayBook WebWorks SDK should be able to re-use these files for signing.  If they cannot find the signing keys, I suspect your system has the %HOMEPATH% variable set to the wrong location.

Try installing both SDKs to the same /Program Files folder and make sure that %HOMEPATH% is correct.